# How to fix large text overflow in cell in jsPDF-AutoTable?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am building a table with some large descriptions and the last lines of the text are hidden behind the next cell.

[resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkE7u.png)

I am using:
"name": "jspdf-autotable",
"version": "3.5.29",

This is the code I am using:

```
head = [[{content: 'My table', colSpan: 3}],
        ['Country', 'Region', 'Comments']]
        
 desc_ltd = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<\nadipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis a tellus fringilla efficitur.'
 desc_dsr = 'a id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat . \n a id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat . \nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adiRRRRR piscing elit.\nNulla iaculis a tellus fringilla efficitur. Nam vehicula eget ligula eu tempor.\n Pellentesque congue lorem vel sapien fermentum orna12ASD3re. Nunc id ornare tellus. Nulla id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricGDFGies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vTREehicula, nibh tellus feugiat ' 
 desc_acl = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaADFSculis a tellus fringilla efficitur. Nam vehicula eget ligula eu tempor. Pellentesque congue lorem vel sapien fermentum ornare. Nunc id ornare tellus. Nu.'
 desc_tml = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis a tellus frinWERWEgilla efficitur. Nam vehicula eget ligula eu tempor. Pellentesque congue lorem vel sapien fermentum ornare. Nunc id ornare tellus. Nulla id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat . a id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat . \na id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat .'
 desc_scl = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis a tellus fringilla efficitur. Nam vehicula eget ligula eu tempor. Pellentesque congue lorem vel sapien fermentum ornare. \nNunc id ornare tellus. Nulla id eros rhoncus turpis commodo ultricies eu nec libero. Fusce porta, sapien sed commodo vehicula, nibh tellus feugiat .'
        
body = [
    ['AAAAAA', 'AA', desc_ltd],
    ['BBBb CC', 'BB', desc_dsr],
    ['CC', 'CC', desc_acl],
    ['AAAAA CC', 'DD', desc_tml],
    ['AAABBb', 'EE', desc_scl],
]

doc.autoTable({
            startY: 0,
            tableWidth: 300,
            headStyles: {  
                halign   : 'center', 
                fillColor: "rgba(  0, 105, 138)",
                textColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255)",
            }, 
            columnStyles: {  // First column style
                0: { 
                    halign   : 'left', 
                    fillColor: "rgba(  0, 105, 138)",
                    textColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255)",
                } 
            }, 
            bodyStyles: { 
                halign: 'left',
            },
            head: head,
            body: body,         
          })
```

I can add a large padding to show it, but the cells with smaller texts become huge and ugly.
It seems that autoTable is having a hard time computing the space needed to fit the whole text.`your text`